# Sort values in a list by columns of a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, matrix

I need to sort the values of each column in a data frame based on the values in a separate matrix. Note that each column is to be sorted independently from other columns (i.e not just sorting by row indice). The matrix have the same dimensions as the dataframe and the values corresponds to the row number that should be returned from the dataframe.

reprex:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data("starwars")
data <- starwars[1:3, 1:3]
data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   name           height  mass
#>   <chr>           <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Luke Skywalker    172    77
#> 2 C-3PO             167    75
#> 3 R2-D2              96    32

sorting_order <- cbind(c(2,3,1),
                       c(3,2,1),
                       c(1,3,2))
sorting_order
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    3    1
#> [2,]    3    2    3
#> [3,]    1    1    2
```

Desired output:

```
#>             name height mass
#> 1          C-3PO     96   77
#> 2          R2-D2    167   32
#> 3 Luke Skywalker    172   75
```

I realise it can be done using a loop, but I am looking for a more efficient way as I will be handling larger data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Base-R approach

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(data), function(x)  data[sorting_order[x,],][,x]))

            name height mass
1          C-3PO     96   77
2          R2-D2    167   77
3 Luke Skywalker     96   75
```

Comment: Not the most easily-read code, but it does the job in one line as well as preserves column classes.

Answer (score 2):

One option using baseR functions:

```
data[] <- Map(`[`, data, split(sorting_order, col(sorting_order)))
data
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  name           height  mass
#  <chr>           <int> <dbl>
#1 C-3PO              96    77
#2 R2-D2             167    32
#3 Luke Skywalker    172    75
```

---

1) From your matrix we create a list of vectors :

```
split(sorting_order, col(sorting_order))
#$`1`
#[1] 2 3 1
#
#$`2`
#[1] 3 2 1
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1 3 2
```

A more straightforward way mentioned in the comments is `asplit`

```
asplit(sorting_order, 2)
```

Thanks to [@GKi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10488504/gki)

2) `Map` is used to rearrange `data` according to the list from 1). Take the first column as an example:

```
data[, 1, drop = TRUE][c(2,3,1)]
#[1] "R2-D2"          "Luke Skywalker" "C-3PO"
```

This is just done for each column.

Comment: The same but using `asplit`: `mapply("[", data, asplit(sorting_order, 2))`